# Preservation of $(C,1)$ summability of a function, when multiplied by a bounded strictly decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a $(C,1)$ summable function defined on $[1,∞)$:
$$ \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int\limits_1^R \left(1−\frac{x}{R}\right)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x= L, $$
where $L$ is a finite number.

Let $g(x)$ be a smooth, strictly decreasing function defined on $[1,∞)$, and satisfying the boundary conditions:
$$ g(1)=1, $$
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x) = 0. $$
**QUESTION**: Under the above conditions, is the function
$$f(x)g(x)$$
necessarily $(C,1)$ summable, or at least $(C,1)$ bounded?

**Remark 1**: G. H. Hardy proved that if $f(x)$
is as defined above, then for any $\delta > 0$ and $g(x)$ defined by
$$g(x)=x^{−\delta},$$
the function $f(x)g(x)$ is indeed $(C,1)$ summable.

**Remark 2**: If we replace the convergence of the $(C,1)$
integral by the convergence of the improper integral
$$ \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int\limits_0^R f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = L < \infty,$$
then it is a classical result that, under the conditions imposed above on $g(x)$, we have
$$ \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \int\limits_0^R f(x) g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = M < \infty.$$

Comment: Is your $f$ nonnegative? If not, can we have $L=-\infty$?

Comment: No, $f$ is not nonnegative. I should have ruled out $L = -\infty$ too. I shall edit it accordingly.

Comment: If $f$ were nonnegative, then its $(C,1)$ summability would imply its integrability, and the question would then have an affirmative answer.